# How to read remote file using urls in Terminal

Tags: ftp

I would like to know if there is a way to read a file on a remote server using url? For example i have been shared a url to a file on a remote server, i need to read it using bash commands or any tool to retrieve data (eg: view first 50 rows and write to a file) without downloading the original file to local system.

The use case is to avoid downloading/uploading huge files located on the remote server to local systems instead access the file content using the url.

Any resources on this would help.

Comment: Your question makes little sense. 1) URL has nothing to do with downloading the file vs. just reading it. 2) To read a file your still need to download it. The only difference may be whether you save the file locally or not. But you cannot save bandwidth/time needed to download the file, if you need to read/process its contents locally.

Comment: Also this does not really look like a programming question.

Comment: I agree it is not a programming question. I am looking at WebDAV which google drive or dropbox uses. My query is mainly to know if using WebDAV or similar technologies will allow processing the file on a local server without downloading while the file is located on a remote server

Comment: downloading- without copying the file physically to the local server or system

Comment: OK, I'll assume that you mean *"without saving file contents to a local file"* - I believe that it is quite obvious that **it is possible**. The server does not care what you do with downloaded data. The server cannot even save the contents to a local file. A client application has to do that. So the client application can as well choose not to do that.

Comment: yes not saving the contents to local file. This is in search of finding ways to process huge files on a remote server, as copying them to local file will need to have space to save the file. Do you have any examples of such clients?

Comment: First, as we agreed already, this is off-topic. So please ask it on appropriate site. And you will have to formulate your problem a way better. It's absolutely not clear how you want to process the file contents. So your choice of a client or a tool will greatly depend on that.